# Does EVE:Valkyrie reward players for deceiving each other?

Tags: eve-valkyrie

I've been reading about this game and wonder if you have to be involved in politics when playing the game or is this only for well-seasoned players? Is deception part of the main goal of the game or just a consequence of the game being a shooter? Could you have a more "peaceful" or passive approach? I have very supeficial knowledge of  the game but for example in other MMORPGs some people focus on trading/crafting items.

I am mainly investigating this claim:

> For example, the MMORPG EVE Online is known for fostering a style of
>   play that involves manipulating and deceiving other players. The VR
>   version of EVE Online, EVE: Valkyrie, has been described as
>   “[u]ndoubtedly the most heavily anticipated virtual reality game.”
>   Based on some of the empirical results surveyed above (see “Illusions
>   of Embodiment and Their Lasting Effect”), there is cause for concern
>   about behavioral patterns rewarded in immersive games such as EVE:
>   Valkyrie having a lasting influence on the psychological profile of
>   users.

Comment: This is my first question on this board and wondering about the reason for downvoting.

Comment: Welcome! The reason for the downvote could be that someone didn't like the way you worded your question or that it shows a lack of research. As a rule here, you shouldn't take downvotes, flags, critical comments or edits as something personal. It's just the system Stack Exchange websites use for their, quite effective I might say, user-based moderation.

Comment: I don't know. The question "what is the win condition of this game?" seems answerable to me. The game also has already been released, so there is no crystal ball required to answer it either.

Comment: @DGarvanski Not taking it personal, I'm well aware of how SE works but unaware of what is allowed or not in the Arqade section :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

> Eve: Valkyrie is a multiplayer dogfighting shooter game set in the Eve Online universe that is designed to use virtual reality headset technology.

It's not connected to EVE Online, both mechanically and in terms of "political" tactics, the only thing in common is the universe. In general, there is no "end goal", apart from winning a multiplayer game. EVE: Valkyrie is not an MMORPG, so it differs greatly from what EVE is.

I guess, the quote you use in your question concerns the lasting effect of "Illusions of Embodiment" with VR games. Especially high-fidelity games, such as EVE: Valkyrie.

Comment: I have edited my question to be more precise if you don't mind updating your answer :-)

Comment: @Emilie Updated it to be more of a comparison between the typical EVE gameplay and EVE: Valkyrie.

Comment: My question concerns EVE: Valkyrie (my bad for tagging with EVE: Online earlier), the claim says the game mechanics foster deception but I am interested to know if deception is specifically rewarded (directly vs. indirectly). I would assume deception is part of any shooter and wondering if there is something special about EVE that makes it more so.

Comment: @Emilie no, none at all. I've played the game and it "rewards deception" as much as any other multiplayer game. The same could be said for any other shooter game, whether it's Overwatch, CS:GO, etc. The only "plus" is that you can flank people from every direction, since it takes place in space and there's no real "plane." It's like I've said before - you fly a spaceship in VR (as awesome as that is) and you shoot at people. The only difference I can see between EVE: Valkyrie and other VR games is that EVE is clearly a finished, full, high-fidelity game.

Comment: That is what I thought and wanted to clear up with actual players, thank you!